# An elegant way of walking a multidimensional dict with a list of keys?

Tags: python, list, recursion, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I want to walk a multidimensional dict using a list of keys.  At the last key, I will return the value.

I'll be given the list and it will map to the keys of the dictionary, but I won't know how deep I'll need to go.  In other words, I won't know beforehand how many items are in the list of keys.

Here's what I came up with.  Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

In my example, walk_to_value() will return "the three value":

```
d = {'one': {'two': {'three': 'the three value'}}}
l = ['one','two','three']

def walk_to_value(d, l):
    e = l.pop(0)
    d1 = d[e]
    if (type(d1) == dict):
            return walk_to_value(d1, l)
    else:
            return d1

print walk_to_value(d, l)
```

Comment: Don't use `type` use `if isinstance(d1, dict):` instead. This is more robust as it'll include objects that inherit from dict as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def walk_to_value(d, l):
    for e in l:
        d = d[e]
    return d
```

I don't think it's useful to return early if there are more keys in the list than levels in the dict, but it's up to you.

Comment: @blakev: there's no need for recursion -- and in a language like Python where implementations often cap the recursion depth, it's often a good idea to avoid it.  I'm not sure what you mean about not walking the tree: on each iterating it takes the appropriate branch.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`reduce()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce):

```
from operator import getitem

def walk_to_value(d, l):
     return reduce(getitem, l, d)
```

or a simple loop:

```
def walk_to_value(d, l):
    result = d
    for field in l:
        result = result[field]
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def traverse_tree(x, looking):
    def f(dic):
        if looking not in dic.keys():
            return reduce(lambda x, y: f(dict(y)) or x, filter(lambda y: isinstance(y, dict), dic.values()), False)
        return dic[looking]
    return f(x)
```

With this, just call 'three' as your looking and it'll find it for you. If three is in the current (top first) it'll return it without checking further in the tree. If it's not, it'll gather all the dicts in the that level and try again. When the key is found, it'll simply return it; otherwise the function returns False.